# package.json npm node scripts not minifying css; not excluding files

Tags: npm-scripts

Here are my package.json scripts...

```
  "scripts": {
"build:sass": "sass  --no-source-map src/assets/scss:dist/assets/css",
"build:js": "uglifyjs-folder ./src/assets/js -o ./dist/assets/js/main.js",
"copy:assets": "copyfiles -e .src/assets/scss/**/* -e .src/assets/js/**/* -u 1 ./src/assets/**/* dist",
"copy:html": "copyfiles -u 1 ./src/*.html dist",
"copy": "npm-run-all --parallel copy:*",
"watch:assets": "onchange \"/src/assets/**/*\" -- npm run copy:assets",
"watch:html": "onchange \"src/*.html\" -- npm run copy:html",
"watch:sass": "sass  --no-source-map --watch src/assets/scss:dist/assets/css",
"watch": "npm-run-all --parallel watch:*",
"serve": "browser-sync start --server dist --files dist",
"start": "npm-run-all copy --parallel watch serve",
"build": "npm-run-all copy:html build:*",
"postbuild": "postcss dist/assets/css/*.css -u autoprefixer cssnano -r --no-map"
  }
```

For this line, I want to exclude the sass and js directories since they are handled by other scripts, but the exclusion isn't working, its still copying all the files in those directories.

```
"copy:assets": "copyfiles -e .src/assets/scss/**/* -e .src/assets/js/**/* -u 1 ./src/assets/**/* dist",
```

And for this line, the css file is updated but it is not minified

```
"watch:sass": "sass  --no-source-map --watch src/assets/scss:dist/assets/css",
```

The build script works. The issues above happen with the start script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was able to get the sass working. But I am having trouble getting the copyfiles to work. I basically want to copy the files in the .src/assets folder to the .dist/assets folder, and want to exclude the .src/assets/scss and the .src/assets/js folders. Any other files and folders will be copied/overwritten. For example, I want to copy the .src/assets/img folder and its files to the .dist/assets/img folder.

I went through the docs for the npm copyfiles and tried various combinations but nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was able to find a work around, sort of. Here is what I did.

I installed the recursive-copy npm package.

```
npm i recursive-copy --save-dev
```

I created a copyfolder.js file in my utils folder with the following contents.

```
import copy from 'recursive-copy';

import { argv } from 'node:process';

const args = process.argv;
const src = args[2];
const dest = args[3];

var options = {overwrite: true,};

try {
    const results = await copy(src, dest, options);
    console.info('Copied ' + results.length + ' files');
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Copy failed: ' + error);
}
```

then i put the following script in my package.json file. Notice it has the arguments that are passed to the copyfolder.js script which are the source and destination directories. Instead of trying to copy all folders with exclusions as I stated in the op, I created a script for each folder I wanted copied. For example I would use it for a Vendors or local bootstrap folder perhaps. My scss/css, images, and js folders are handled by the minifyers/compilers. The copyfolder is used for any other content I want to put in my dist or public builds.

```
"copyfolder:utils": "node utils/copyfolder.js ./src/assets/test ./dist/assets/test"
```

I also put a script in the package.json file that uses the npm onchange package to run the above copyfolder:utils script when anything in the source folder changes.

```
"watch:utils": "onchange \"src/assets/test/**/*\" -- npm run copyfolder:utils"
```